# Calculate a value based on Auto Increment ID & other field before saving

Tags: laravel, model, migration

the use case is where I want to generate a calculated value using the auto-increment ID and another column to set a column value at the time of record insert.

Here is the code I am using:

```
public static function boot()
{
    parent::boot();
    Order::saving(function (Order $order) {
         $order->total = $order->id * $order->quantity;
    });
}
```

(it a dummy use case, actual column and logic is remove to ease of understanding).

The above code doesn't work with ID field since this is the default auto increment field, but it works fine with the other columns.

Can anyone suggest a solution here?

Answer (score 0):

When a new model is saved for the first time, the `creating` and `created` events will fire. If a model already existed in the database and the `save` method is called, the `updating` / `updated` events will fire. However, in both cases, the `saving` / `saved` events will fire.

```php
public static function boot()
{
    parent::boot();
    Order::created(function (Order $order) {
         $order->total = $order->id * $order->quantity;
    });
}
```

`$order->id` is exists now.